# MVC Remote jquery validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a form that performs a Remote validation check when a button is clicked, after which a javascript routine is performed.  I do not want the form to submit or the validation to occur on a key stroke or focus out.

With this in mind, I created a Model with a Remote attribute...

```
public class Home
{
    [Remote("CheckMessage", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Message is wrong")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Within the controller there is the code for the CheckMessage routine (set to return false for testing)...

```
    public JsonResult CheckMessage(string message)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The cshtml page then contains the following form...

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "login-form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message)

    @Html.TextBox("result")

    <input type="button" id="click" value="Click" />
}
```

With the following script...

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // so the validation is performed on the button click only
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            onkeyup: false,
            onfocusout: false,
        });

        $('#login-form').validate();

        // validate form on button click and show returned success in "result" textbox
        $('#click').click(function () {
            var result = $('#login-form').valid();
            $('input[name="result"]').val(result);
        });
    })
</script>
```

However, what happens is the following..

1. When the button is clicked without letters no server side code is called but "true" set in the "result" textbox
2. Entering letters into the "message" textbox and clicking the button does fire the server side code and the message's "ValidationMessageFor" control displays the error message "Message is wrong" but the "result" textbox still displays "true"
3. And now when any letters are entered into the "message" textbox again, the server side code fires immediately (seemingly now ignoring the default set) and the error message "Message is wrong" now appears in the "ValidationSummary" control. The "result" textbox is still returning "true".

I am obviously doing something fundamentally incorrect, I just need to be told where as I've been working on this for days now!

1. How do I get the correct return value from "valid()"?
2. How do I ensure the server side code is only called on a button click always?
3. How do I get the error message to appear correctly (ideally in just the "ValidationSummary" control)?

Thank you.

Comment: The `[Remote]` attribute works with `jquery.validate.js` and ``jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (no other scripts required)

Comment: Both of those scripts are included.

Comment: Then delete all your scripts. As soon as you tab out of the textbox, the `CheckMessage()` method will be called and "Message is wrong" will be displayed

Comment: But I only want the Remote validation to occur when the button is clicked, not key press or tab out of the textbox.

Comment: Then remove the `[Remote]` attribute and just make a normal jquery ajax call to the method and display display a message in the success callback

Comment: Thanks, that would be a solution. I've not used Remote before but from what I've read I thought what I'm trying to do would be achievable with it.

Comment: Add [Required] attribute also

Comment: No its not. As I noted, `[Remote]` works with the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and is triggered when you tab out of the control.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the default behaviour of query validate by using `$.validator.setDefaults` like I have tried, so it doesn't trigger on a keypress or focus out.

Comment: @spaceduk. All you have done is prevent it from ever triggering. And your code is just screwing up all client side validation. Either use it as it was designed or delete the attribute and do you own ajax call.